# RSS feed link broken , only loading after wordpress admin login

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, rss

I am trying to open my rss feed link but it is not loading. Only loading when I logged in WordPress admin panel.

I don't know why it is happening. Please help me out with this problem.

Rss Fedd Url  : http://odishatv.in/feed

Answer (score 0):

I got the proper solution through the given link below.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rss-feed-broken-for-the-rest-of-the-world-only-loading-for-blog-admin/